# d3.js chart not updated with new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

A series of rectangles are plotted using `d3.js` by fetching an array of 100 objects. Although the `console.log(data)` shows that new data are being retrieved, the new data points do not seem to be appending any rectangles.

Was `.enter().append()` used incorrectly?

```
function init() {
    var width = 800,
        height = 400,
        margin = 50;

    chart = d3.select('#chart')
                .append('svg:svg')
                .attr('width', width)
                .attr('height', height);
}

function do_update() {
    data = fetch_latest_top100();
    console.log(data)

    chart.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('svg:rect')
        .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.y); })
        .attr('height', function(d) { return d.value; })
        .attr('width', function(d) { return 3 });
}
```

**jsfiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/BU8cA/

Comment: it would be better if you include a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) or plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue which would help in seeing issue live

Comment: I don't know if it's a copy/paste issue but you're missing a ")" after y(d.y on the y attr, and that could be the error

Comment: @tomtomtom Copy-paste issue, corrected the typo, thanks!

Comment: try removing the svg: before the rect then, since you are already selecting the svg, like so: .append("rect") if it's not that I don't see anything else strange from this code

Comment: @tomtomtom I included the jsfiddle in the post. The data from the 2nd fetch does not seem to do anything to the chart.

Comment: I think I can be of no help here, sorry but I am not that familiar with d3 either. If you have not seen this yet, it might help: http://mbostock.github.io/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem with your update method is that it ONLY handles new element, and does not update the existing elements to match their new data.  After you have created the new rectangles with your enter() selection, you have to go back to your complete selection (new and changing rectangles) to set the attributes that are going to change.

The easiest way to do this is to store the selection in a variable at the point where you have applied the data function but before you call the enter method, like this:

```
   var rects = chart.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data);

   rects.enter()
        .append('svg:rect')
        .attr('width', function(d) { return 3 }); 
       // since the width is constant, you only need to set it once

   rects.exit().remove(); //if the number of data points might shrink

   rects.attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.x); })
        .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.y); })
        .attr('height', function(d) { return d.value; });
   //note that this now includes the rectangles created with enter()
   //as well as the old ones you are resizing / repositioning
```

That should get the right data in, but you still have a layout problem (on the fiddle, anyway), in that your y values aren't being set correctly.  The y value is the position of the top of the rectangle, so if you want bars that look like they are all sitting on the same line you need to adjust it based on the height of the bar.  Mike Bostock's tutorial and demo here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/bar/3/

---

**Update for D3 version 4+**

Elements appended to the "enter" selection are no longer automatically added to the main (update) selection.  You now need to explicitly create a "merge" selection, by calling the [`merge`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/master/README.md#selection_merge) method on the "enter" selection:

```
var rects = chart.selectAll('rect')
    .data(data);

rects.exit().remove(); //if the number of data points might shrink

rects.enter()
    .append('svg:rect')
    .attr('width', function(d) { return 3 }) // since the width is constant, you only need to set it once

  .merge(rects) 
          //merge the newly added elements into the main selection
          //of existing elements to update
    .attr('x', function(d) { return x(d.x); })
    .attr('y', function(d) { return y(d.y); })
    .attr('height', function(d) { return d.value; });
```

Comment: Is this answer still valid? If I call rects.nodes() after the call to rects.enter().append(), I still get back an empty array. If the above claim that "this now includes the rectangles created with enter()" were true, shouldn't I expect to see a populated array, rather than an empty one on my call to .nodes()?

Comment: @mevans Are you using D3 v4?  It changed how merges work considerably, see [Mike Bostock's overview of the reasoning behind the changes](https://medium.com/@mbostock/what-makes-software-good-943557f8a488). You now need to explicitly call `selection.merge()` to combine the enter and update selections.

Comment: Yes - I am using D3 v4. The introduction of .merge() and the change of enter/update (which now function contrary to the majority of examples on the web) was maddening. Thanks so much for the clarification.

Comment: @AmeliaBR  Can you please look over this problem and help how to solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39998877/total-height-of-stacked-bar-on-tip-of-every-rectangle-in-stacked-bar-chart-using