# Total height of Stacked Bar on tip of every rectangle in stacked Bar Chart using d3

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, charts

I drawn a stackedbar Chart in which now I trying to place the Total value(I mean the yaxis value) on tip of the every rectangle. I have coded to fetch the details but here the problem is I am getting Every Layer value on tip of every layer but i need to show only the last layer value.

the problem is shown in below fig's.[image][image]

My code is Shown below

```
var fData =    
[{"orders":"A","Total_Orders":76,"A_Lines":123,"B_Lines":0,"C_Lines":0,"D_Lines":0,"Total_Lines":123,"Total_Units":3267},
{"orders":"B","Total_Orders":68,"A_Lines":0,"B_Lines":107,"C_Lines":0,"D_Lines":0,"Total_Lines":107,"Total_Units":3115},
{"orders":"C","Total_Orders":81,"A_Lines":0,"B_Lines":0,"C_Lines":123,"D_Lines":0,"Total_Lines":123,"Total_Units":3690},
{"orders":"D","Total_Orders":113,"A_Lines":0,"B_Lines":0,"C_Lines":0,"D_Lines":203,"Total_Lines":203,"Total_Units":7863},
{"orders":"AB","Total_Orders":62,"A_Lines":70,"B_Lines":76,"C_Lines":0,"D_Lines":0,"Total_Lines":146,"Total_Units":1739},
{"orders":"AC","Total_Orders":64,"A_Lines":77,"B_Lines":0,"C_Lines":79,"D_Lines":0,"Total_Lines":156,"Total_Units":2027},
{"orders":"AD","Total_Orders":100,"A_Lines":127,"B_Lines":0,"C_Lines":0,"D_Lines":144,"Total_Lines":271,"Total_Units":6467},
{"orders":"BC","Total_Orders":64,"A_Lines":0,"B_Lines":80,"C_Lines":84,"D_Lines":0,"Total_Lines":164,"Total_Units":1845},
{"orders":"BD","Total_Orders":91,"A_Lines":0,"B_Lines":108,"C_Lines":0,"D_Lines":135,"Total_Lines":243,"Total_Units":4061},
{"orders":"CD","Total_Orders":111,"A_Lines":0,"B_Lines":0,"C_Lines":132,"D_Lines":147,"Total_Lines":279,"Total_Units":5011},
{"orders":"ABC","Total_Orders":45,"A_Lines":58,"B_Lines":63,"C_Lines":55,"D_Lines":0,"Total_Lines":176,"Total_Units":1245},
{"orders":"ABD","Total_Orders":69,"A_Lines":105,"B_Lines":87,"C_Lines":0,"D_Lines":116,"Total_Lines":308,"Total_Units":4538},
{"orders":"ACD","Total_Orders":66,"A_Lines":91,"B_Lines":0,"C_Lines":88,"D_Lines":132,"Total_Lines":311,"Total_Units":4446},{
{"orders":"BCD","Total_Orders":68,"A_Lines":0,"B_Lines":84,"C_Lines":95,"D_Lines":111,"Total_Lines":290,"Total_Units":4187},
{"orders":"ABCD","Total_Orders":56,"A_Lines":96,"B_Lines":90,"C_Lines":93,"D_Lines":143,"Total_Lines":422,"Total_Units":6331}] 
var headers = ["A_Lines", "B_Lines", "C_Lines", "D_Lines"];
            var colors = ["#9999CC", "#F7A35C", "#99CC99", "#CCCC99"];
            var colorScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
                               .domain(headers)
                               .range(colors);
            var layers = d3.layout.stack()(headers.map(function (count) {
                return fData.map(function (d, i) {
                    // alert(d);
                    return { x: d.ORDER_TYPE, y: +d[count], color: colorScale(count) };
                });
            }));
            //StackedBar Rectangle Max

            var yStackMax = d3.max(layers, function (layer) { return d3.max(layer, function (d) { return d.y0 + d.y; }); });
            // Set x, y and colors
            var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
         .domain(layers[0].map(function (d) { return d.x; }))
         .rangeRoundBands([25, width], .08);

            var y = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, yStackMax])
                .range([height, 0]);

            //    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
            //.domain(headers)
            // .range(["#9999CC", "#F7A35C", "#99CC99", "#CCCC99"]);

            // Define and draw axes
            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(xScale)
                        .tickSize(1)
                        .tickPadding(6)
                        .orient("bottom");

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                        .scale(y)
                        .orient("left")
                        .tickFormat(d3.format(".2s"));

            var layer = svg.selectAll(".layer")
                .data(layers)
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "layer")
                .style("fill", function (d, i) { return colorScale(i); });

            var rect = layer.selectAll("rect")
                .data(function (d) { return d; })
                .enter().append("rect")
                .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(d.x); })
                .attr("y", height)
                .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand())
                .attr("height", 0)
                .attr("class", function (d) {
                    return "rect bordered " + "color-" + d.color.substring(1);
                });



            layer.selectAll("text.rect")
             .data(function (layer) { return layer; })
             .enter().append("text")
             .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
             .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(d.x) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2; })
             .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.y + d.y0) - 3; })
             .text(function (d) { return d.y + d.y0; })
             .style("fill", "4682b4");


            //********** AXES ************
            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                .call(xAxis)
                .selectAll("text").style("text-anchor", "end")
                    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
                    .attr("dy", ".15em")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "rotate(-45)"
                    });

            svg.attr("class", "x axis")
               .append("text")
               .attr("text-anchor", "end")  // this makes it easy to centre the text as the transform is applied to the anchor
               .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2) + "," + (height + 60) + ")")  // centre below axis
               .text("Order Velocity Group");


            svg.append("g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(20,0)")
                .call(yAxis)
              .append("text")
                .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
                .attr({ "x": -75, "y": -70 })
                .attr("dy", ".75em")
                .style("text-anchor", "end")
                .text("No. Of Lines");

            //********** LEGEND ************

            var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
                        .data(headers.slice().reverse())
                    .enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "legend")
                    .attr("transform", function (d, i) { return "translate(" + i * (-100) + "," + (height + 50) + ")"; });

            legend.append("rect")
                .attr("x", width - 18)
                .attr("width", 18)
                .attr("height", 18)
            //.style("fill", color);
                .style("fill", function (d, i) { return colors[i]; })
                .on("mouseover", function (d, i) {
                            svg.selectAll("rect.color-" + colors[i].substring(1)).style("stroke", "blue");
                                })
                .on("mouseout", function (d, i) {
                            svg.selectAll("rect.color-" + colors[i].substring(1)).style("stroke", "white");
                                });

            legend.append("text")
                  .attr("x", width - 24)
                  .attr("y", 9)
                  .attr("dy", ".35em")
                  .style("text-anchor", "end")
                  .text(function (d) { return d; });


            transitionStacked();
            function transitionStacked() {

                y.domain([0, yStackMax]);

                rect.transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .delay(function (d, i) { return i * 10; })
                    .attr("y", function (d) { return y(d.y0 + d.y); })
                    .attr("height", function (d) { return y(d.y0) - y(d.y0 + d.y); })
                  .transition()
                    .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(d.x); })
                    .attr("width", xScale.rangeBand());

                rect.on('mouseover', tip.show)
                .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

            };
```

can anyone help me.

Comment: do you want to show a tip with the total sum of all layers in the hovered rect item?

Comment: No I am expecting the total sum on bar as a text as in second image (not on hover just display as a text above rect)

Comment: The error is getting every layer value but i need only the above layer value to place. Your can get the problem if you closely look at the "ABC"  on x-axis of both images

Comment: @charantej I can help you, but I need you to provide the exact code that you used to make that image you pasted. This code in your question has a lot of errors and `undefined`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you need: First, we'll set `fData` as the data for the texts:

```
layer.selectAll("text.rect")
    .data(fData)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
```

But, as this dataset doesn't have the correct yScale value, we'll have to extract it using a filter:

```
.attr("y", function (d) { 
    var filtered = fData.filter(function(e){ 
        return e.Total_Units == d.Total_Units
    });
    return y(filtered[0].Total_Lines) - 3; 
})
```

All together:

```
layer.selectAll("text.rect")
    .data(fData)
    .enter().append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
        return xScale(d.orders) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
        var filtered = fData.filter(function(e) {
            return e.Total_Units == d.Total_Units
        });
        return y(filtered[0].Total_Lines) - 3;
    })
    .text(function(d) {
        return d.Total_Units
    })
    .style("fill", "4682b4");
```

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wnwb6meh/

Comment: the same I tried but here the problem is it is placing the text on every Stacked Bar. Like if one Bar contains more than one part it is placing on every part. I need only on last(above) part.

Comment: I tried it before itself but here the problem is I need to place only on top of last Stacked Bar but it is placing on every bar. Because if the Refer the ABC bar on my fig1 in Question. if height of A and B Stacked Bar on ABC is very less then the Total we are placing are overlapping.

Comment: Soory for my mistake I have same graph with units on Y-axis so I mentioned to place Units( That's the Reason Yaxis doesn't match). You can place Total_Lines on Bar

Comment: @charantej check the new answer.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply with solution. It worked alot but the color of the text I mean(Steel blue which I used) is not applied in Explorer or firefox browser. Can You know any changes for this.

Comment: No, sorry, I can't help you with IE or Firefox, I suggest you post another question regarding this. If this solution works for you, please consider accepting the answer or at least upvoting it, that way people will be more inclined to help you next time.

Comment: Thanks it worked. The color not referring can be solved using direct name like blue,black or something. not with rgb value